# Free/Open Source DataEase provider

Tags: database, jdbc, odbc, oledb

Anyone know of a free/open source OLEDB/ODBC/JDBC driver against [DataEase](http://www.dataease.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try in http://www.sourceforge.net

Comment: I past time i converted a project from DataEase to VB.NEt and used a solution named OpenDE.NET is a .net System.Data specific object like System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of something else?  OpenDE.NET is for simulating articulated rigid body dynamics.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't find anything like System.Data because is very complex to do.